Linear time approximate multiplication
I was searching for the following simple thing, but to my surprise couldn't find anything online.
Is there a linear time approximation algorithm for multiplication or for division. Meaning,

Given I=$[a,b]\in N^2$
Is there an algorithm outputing a number $y \inΘ(\frac{a}{b})$ in $O(|I|)$ time  ?
Is there an algorithm outputing a number $y \inΘ(a b)$ in $O(|I|)$ time ?

The asymptotically fastest known algorithm for multiplication is in $O(I \log{I})$, due to David Harvey.
My naive guess is that there is even an algorithm computing  $ab+ο(ab)$ in linear time and $ο(ab)$ is just as big enough to not trivially allow $o(I \log{I})$ time computation of $ab$, or something of this nature, using probably some variant of David Harvey's recent multiplication algorithm, but the probably suffices for my use case. I would say what I tried, but I decided to post before overthinking, in case the answer is obvious (and to exist on the internet).
Note: By $y \inΘ(a b)$, I mean that the absolute values of $y$ is bounded by a constant * $ab$, where the constant depends on only the algorithm.

What does $|I|$ represent?  Do you mean $|A|=b-a$?  What does $I \log I$ represent?  What domain does $y$ come from? Do you want the nearest integer, or do you want a floating point number, or something else?

If $|I| = b-a$, how would you return an integer in $\Theta(ab)$ in $\mathcal{O}(|I|)$ time, in the case $|I| = 1$ and $a, b$ very big? It would not take a constant time to even compute $|I|$ (unless you already know it).

The input vector $I$ is a vector of two natural numbers. And $|I|$ is the size of the input. $O(|I|)$ think of $O(\log_2{a} +\log_2{b})$

If you just want a $\Theta(ab)$ precision then we can just consider the binary representation of $a, b$, and we can easily get two "ceiling" power of 2:
$$
a' = \min \{ 2^w | 2^w \ge a\} \\
b' = \min \{ 2^w | 2^w \ge b\}
$$
Then we know $a \le a' \lt 2a, b \le b' \lt 2b$.
Clearly we can just compute the product $a' \cdot b'$ within $O(|I|)$ time and we know:
$ab \le a'b' \lt 4ab$ or $ab \le a'b' \le (2a-1)(2b-1)$. (Thanks to SilvioM)
If we want approximation ratio to be $1+\epsilon$, we can derive a similar algorithm.
Let's say the binary representation of $a$ is $\overline{n_1 n_2 \cdots n_k}$ where $k = \log_2a$. Then we consider an approximation of $a$ to be $a' = \overline{n_1 n_2 \cdots n_t 0 0 \cdots 0}$ in binary representation, i.e. we truncate the binary representation by taking only first $t$ bits, here $t \lt k$.
Then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{a'} &= \frac{\overline{n_1n_2\cdots n_t} \cdot 2^{k-t} + \overline{n_{t+1}\cdots n_k}}{\overline{n_1n_2\cdots n_t} \cdot 2^{k-t}} \\
\\
&= 1 + \frac{\overline{n_{t+1}\cdots n_k}}{\overline{n_1n_2\cdots n_t} \cdot 2^{k-t}}
\\
\\
&\le 1 + \frac{2^{k-t}-1}{2^{k-1}} \\
\\
&\lt 1 + \frac{1}{2^{t-1}}
\end{align*}
Similarly we can have $b'$ for $b$ with the same approximation ratio.
Since we only consider $t$ bits for multiplication, the time complexity would be $O(t\log t)$ with approximation ratio $(1 + \frac{1}{2^{t-2}})^2$.
Take $t = 2 + \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and we can get roughly the expected ratio $1 + \epsilon$.

Correct. Do you see an immediate way to make an linear-time algorithm with (1+ε) ,
ε arbitrarily small instead of 4?

Just a detail: we know that $a^{\prime} < 2a$ and $b^{\prime} < 2b$, so we can get $ab \leq a^{\prime} b^{\prime} < 4ab$, or, since we are talking about integers,  $ab \leq a^{\prime} b^{\prime} \leq (2a-1)(2b-1)$.

@JohnKall If you'd like a $1+\epsilon$ approximation, we can have an algorithm runs roughly in $t \log t$ where $t=2+\log \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Very nicely written, I will accept the answer. Now it looks like there a definitely an algorithm for $(1+ο(1))ab$, idk about the $ab+ο(1)$ yet. A speculation (warning: mumbo jumbo): if you mix up the numbers a bit with fourier somehow use more than the first few digits and take the max of linear-time approximate norm to restrict the search space. Maybe you can solve this; I think this is important work from a CS perspective.

Upon further thought I realized the best there might be is a linear time algorithm to compute $ab+\ $ like $Θ(\sqrt{ab})$ (perhaps add a log factor) and then notice you can compute $ab$ to good accuracy taking the average of $O(\log{\max\{a,b\}})$ such estimations (from the central limit theorem on the average error) so thats $O(n\log{n})$ timesteps in total.
And it seems very plausible a such algorithm exists because the error term is very standard see for example the error term in Gauss circle problem or the Riemann hypothesis estimation of the prime number function $π(x)$ or (# denotes number of) |#ones$-$#zeros|=$n$/2+O($\sqrt{n}$) of a kolmogorov random number of length $n$.
